# How do I copy values below the existing value until the next non-blank value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I tried to search a bit, but it's difficult to describe it in words, so it wasn't easy to find (and in the right language).

Given:

```
  A B C
1 1
2
3
4 2
5
6 3
7
8
9
0
```

Wanted result:

```
  A B C D
1 1     1
2       1
3       1
4 2     2
5       2
6 3     3
7       3
8       3
9       3
0       3
```

Comment: `df['D']=df.ffill(1).iloc[:,-1].ffill()`

Comment: @anky_91 wouldn't `df['D'] = df['A'].ffill()` suffice?

Comment: @MohitMotwani if data is only in A yes :)

Comment: @anky_91 if not only in A, how does your code work differently?

Comment: @MohitMotwani i interpreted this as get the last valid value accross each columns, something like if the df is like : `pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,np.nan],'B':[np.nan,np.nan,2]})` and expected output is `1,2,2` ,  you would do `df.ffill(1).iloc[:,-1]` with `ffill` if required

Answer (score 2):

Your DataFrame has not *NaN* in "empty" cells, so I assume that:

- the *dtype* of each column is *object* (actually *string*),
- "empty" cells contain either an **empty string** or a **space**.

In such case, one of possible solutions is:

- replace empty strings / spaces with *NaN*,
- call *ffill*.

Something like:

```
df['D'] = df.A.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True).ffill()
```

## Edit

If values to "copy down" can be in **any** column (not only in *A*),
then the solution is:

```
df['D'] = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True).ffill(axis=1)\
    .iloc[:, -1].ffill()
```

Similarly to proposed by *Anky* in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

Full answer based on @Mohit Motwani's comment:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, None, None], [None]*3,[None]*3,
                   [2,None,None], [None]*3,
                   [3,None,None], [None]*3, [None]*3, [None]*3,], 
                  columns=["A","B","C"] )

print(df)

df["D"] = df["A"].ffill()

print(df)
```

Output before:

```
     A     B     C
0  1.0  None  None
1  NaN  None  None
2  NaN  None  None
3  2.0  None  None
4  NaN  None  None
5  3.0  None  None
6  NaN  None  None
7  NaN  None  None
8  NaN  None  None
```

Output after:

```
     A     B     C    D
0  1.0  None  None  1.0
1  NaN  None  None  1.0
2  NaN  None  None  1.0
3  2.0  None  None  2.0
4  NaN  None  None  2.0
5  3.0  None  None  3.0
6  NaN  None  None  3.0
7  NaN  None  None  3.0
```